# How does using node pointer in linked list changes the recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I used a temporary node 'nextnode' to point to the next node of `head` or `cur`:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedListNode* head) {
    if ( head == NULL ) return NULL;
    SinglyLinkedListNode *nextnode = head->next;
    while ( nextnode != NULL && head->data == nextnode->data ) {
        nextnode = nextnode->next;
    }
    head->next = removeDuplicates( nextnode );
    return head;
}
```

This code works fine ...but if I change

```
head->next = removeDuplicates( nextnode );
```

to

```
head->next = removeDuplicates( head->next);
```

the code outputs the same list as the input.

But if I remove `nextnode` in all places and use `head->next` in place of `nextnode`, the code works fine!

What is actually happening, that's making it work? What am I missing?

What happens in this code when using `head->next` and `nextnode`? I just want to understand how this works in memory allocation to understand recursion better.

Comment: Just draw it on a piece of paper, keeping track of how `nextnode` and `head->next` change during the execution. Take for example the list [1]->[1]->[2]->[2]->[3]. Show what you did to follow these modifications step by step.

Comment: i only know it works in case of removeduplicate(head->next) ...i dont know how it works in case of removeduplicates(nextnode)...in the later case, does the value of head, not change? or does it change the value of nextnode if then does it go to next node acc to head->next or nextnode->next

Comment: In c++, prefer to use `nullptr`

Comment: ohh okay! that makes sense ..thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example this list:

```
head
  ↓
  1 → 2 → 2 → 3 → 3 → 3 → 4
```

In the first call of the function, `nextnode` will point to [2], and the `while` condition will immediately be false as the data is different (1 != 2). So we have:

```
head  nextnode
  ↓   ↓  
  1 → 2 → 2 → 3 → 3 → 3 → 4
```

Then the first recursive call is made, and in that execution context, there is another `head` variable, which is set to the value of the caller's `nextnode`. To better track this `head` variable, I will call it `head2`, and will keep referring to `head` when we speak of the variable in the original call:

```
head head2
  ↓   ↓  
  1 → 2 → 2 → 3 → 3 → 3 → 4
```

A new `nextnode` variable is created, and this time the `while` loop will go through one iteration, because there is a duplicate value (2). The iteration stops when `nextnode` points to the node with 3:

```
head head2  nextnode
  ↓   ↓       ↓   
  1 → 2 → 2 → 3 → 3 → 3 → 4
```

Another recursive call is made. Again we get a new `head` variable, which I will call `head3`:

```
head head2  head3
  ↓   ↓       ↓   
  1 → 2 → 2 → 3 → 3 → 3 → 4
```

Again, a new `nextnode` will be created. This time it ends up pointing to the node with 4:

```
head head2  head3       nextnode
  ↓   ↓       ↓           ↓
  1 → 2 → 2 → 3 → 3 → 3 → 4
```

An even deeper recursive call is made:

```
head head2  head3       head4
  ↓   ↓       ↓           ↓
  1 → 2 → 2 → 3 → 3 → 3 → 4
```

This time the new `nextnode` variable will become `NULL`, and so we make a recursive call with argument `NULL`. We are at the end of the recursion, as this deepest call will immediately return `NULL`. We go back to where the call was made and see that `head4->next` is assigned this `NULL`. In this case this assignment does not make a difference, as `head4->next` was already `NULL`.

We backtrack to the previous level in the recursion tree: `head4` is returned. And there we do see a modification happening. This returned `head4` is assigned to `head3->next`, and so the second & third node with value 3 are both kicked out of the list with just one assignment:

```
head head2  head3       head4
  ↓   ↓       ↓           ↓
  1 → 2 → 2 → 3 →         4
```

We backtrack one more step, and this time `head3` is returned to be assigned to `head2->next`. Now the second node with value 2 is kicked out:

```
head head2  head3   head4
  ↓   ↓       ↓       ↓
  1 → 2 →     3 →     4
```

One more backtracking: `head2` is returned to be assigned to `head->next`. This makes no difference as `head->next` already pointed to `head2`. The top-level function call returns the `head` and we're done.

### With `head->next = removeDuplicates( head->next);`

This change will indeed destroy the algorithm. It makes the value of `nextnode` irrelevant. The `while` loop is now doing work for nothing, as the code does not make use of the new value of `nextnode`. You might as well remove that loop and the variable `nextnode`, and then it is obvious that no node is ever removed.

**A key observation is that `removeDuplicates` always returns the node you passed to it as argument**, so the altered statement is really doing:

```
head->next = head->next
```

...which is doing nothing, and it is the *only* place in the code where the list chain is altered. At no other place is a `next` property changed.

> if I remove `nextnode` in all places and use `head->next` in place of `nextnode`, the code works fine!

Indeed. And in that case, the function doesn't need to return anything, because duplicate-removal never needs to change the `head` of a list. So the code would then look like this:

```
void removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedListNode* head) {
  if ( head == NULL ) return;
  while ( head->next != NULL && head->data == head->next->data ) {
    head->next = head->next->next;
  }
  removeDuplicates( head->next );
}
```

We could again make the same analysis as at the top of this answer for an example list (please do so on a piece of paper), and you would conclude that it would also effectively remove the duplicates. The difference is that here the actual removal happens one node at a time in the `while` loop (each iteration removes exactly one node), while in the original code it happens during backtracking, where it can actually remove multiple duplicate nodes in one go (as we saw in the case of `3 → 3 → 3 → 4` becoming `3 → 4` in one assignment), so in general the original code can sometimes do the job with fewer assignments, certainly when there is a lot of repetition of values in the list.

There are also fewer `->next` references in the original code.

Because of these differences, the original code will in theory run a bit faster.